# Delayed execution when writing to ToC in amsart

Tags: table-of-contents, amsart

Consider the following example using the [`amsart` document class](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsart):

```
\documentclass{amsart}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsart
\newcommand{\addtotoc}[1]{\addtocontents{toc}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{First section}
\addtotoc{abc}
\section{Second section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\addtotoc{def}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\end{document}
```

The document class `amsart` seems to exhibit a delay in processing content to the table of contents; here is the `.toc` file's content:

```
\contentsline {section}{\tocsection {}{1}{First section}}{1}
abc
\contentsline {section}{\tocsection {}{2}{Second section}}{1}
def
\contentsline {subsection}{\tocsubsection {}{2.1}{First subsection}}{1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\tocsubsection {}{2.2}{Second subsection}}{1}
```

[image: ToC]

Why does the entry `abc` end up after the first section (as expect), but `def` does not end up after the first subsection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very same problem arises already with `article` class, and `paragraph`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\addtotoc}[1]{\addtocontents{toc}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\tableofcontents

\section{First section}
\addtotoc{abc\endgraf}
\section{Second section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\addtotoc{def\endgraf}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\paragraph{A paragraph}% insert \leavevmode to cure the problem
\addtotoc{ghk\endgraf}
\end{document}
```

Be it with `amsart+subsection` or `article+paragraph` the cure is to add `\leavevmode` before the `\addtotoc`.

What happens is that the `\addcontentsline` originating in the subsection will be executed only as part of things put in an `\everypar`, hence at the start of the next paragraph. Doing `\par` does not help  because we are in vertical mode: immediately after `\subsection{First subsection}` the subsection title has not been typeset yet.

Thus `\addtotoc` is encountered first, while still in vertical mode, and thus stuff ends up in the `.aux` file before the corresponding instruction originating the subsection title itself. This order is the naturally preserved in the `.toc` file.

[image of toc done with article class exhibiting the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWUdW.png)

(one might wonder how the last `\addcontentsline` ever gets executed, but at the end of the document a `\clearpage` is done, and `\if@noskipsec` is `\iftrue` this does the `\leavevmode` thing)

Comment: So run-in headings is the key here. Thanks.